# Curl Call return nothing from Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, amazon-ec2

Question: How can I allow my rails app to allow outbound curl calls which is hosted on Amazon EC2?

Explanation: I have a rails app I am using to make API calls. I have it hosted on an EC2 Instance. The rails app makes a curl call to complete an Oauth process and returns the auth and refresh token. This works on my LocalHost, but on EC2 it does not return the tokens.

So far I have update my security group to allow outbound/inbound calls anywhere on port 80 and I can confirm my curl call works outside of the EC2 instance. This is my first project using a lot of AWS, thank you in advanced.

Code:

```
def getTokenW
   logger.debug("WHAT IS MY CODE #{params[:auth_code]}")
   #Curl call for token
   gtToken = `curl --data " curl call with auth_code"`

   logger.debug("response #{gtToken}")  !!!NO RESPONSE!!!

   tknArray = gtToken.split("\n")

    render json: {
      status: :ok,
      message: "#{tknArray[-1]}"
    }.to_json
end
```

Comment: Can you share the actual curl response?

Comment: @emaillenin I don't want to share the secret_Id and what not. The curl command works from my LocalHost and terminal. I am expecting the response to come back as a string because of the ` ` ... Also it is only valid for 30seconds because of the auth_code

Answer (score 0):

What I did to solve. I downgraded to Unbuntu 16.04. I checked to see if i could run curl commands from the EC2 terminal and then everything was solved. Apparently 18.04 has some dependencies issues that confused the system.